# Android notification when media file is done playing

Tags: android, media-player

I have a `mediaplayer` class with all the methods in there. I am just trying to get an indication of when a file is done playing, but I'm having trouble.
Here is the method:

```
public boolean isPlaying()
{
    final boolean still_playing = true;
    mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
        {
            still_playing = false;
        }
    });
    return still_playing;
}
```

I'm getting errors like `the final local variable cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type` or when I try something different I get `variabledeclaratorIdexpected`
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your `final boolean still_playing = true;` is a constant variable which means it can't be changed during runtime.

Later in the program:

```
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
{
    still_playing = false;
}
```

You're trying to change it's value.

To fix this you should define `boolean still_playing = true;` as a member variable of the class like sow:

```
public class classExample {
    // member variables
    private boolean still_playing = true;

    public boolean isPlaying() {

        /* I DELETED THE VARIABLE AND DECLARED IT OUTSIDE THE METHOD */

        mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
             @Override
             public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                  /* You could declare it here too without the private
                     keyword like this:
                             boolean still_playing = true; */

                  still_playing = false;
             }
        });
        return still_playing;
    }
}
```